# CFA in Amos - Is my model correct for my analysis?

Tags: confirmatory-factor, amos

I want to do an CFA on a questionaire with four subscales in my sample, because I need to know, if they are independent from each other.
I added all items to each subscale and then drew the covariances. Is this the correc tmodel to check, if my four subscales are independent (or uncorrelated)?
(Please forgive me for the terrible oversized fonts, Im pretty new at this).

[image: My Model]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would test whether each of the parameter estimates between the latent variables are 0. I would first test them as a group, and then individually. You will get p-values for each of them in this model, but I would also estimate models where you constrain each of them to 0, and all of them to 0, that way you can look at all the different fit statistics:
- AIC/BIC or other likelihood-based criteria 
- LR test (since the models are nested)
- compare RMSEA
- compare goodness of fit indices like TLI, etc.

You should hopefully see that all of these tests agree in which model fits the best. Since these are ostensibly real data, not simulated data, you will not find a 0 covariance between them, but the statistical tests and fit tests should show you if the model with 0 covariance among them has an equal fit (it will not likely be absolutely better, unless your sample size is small, because an unconstrained model should always fit better).

Comment: Ok, so I did the analysis and the covariances between the 4 latent variables are .08 or smaller. Seems nice :) But I have values higher than 1 on many of the paths between my measured variables and the latens variables. How can this be?

Comment: For covariance between latent variables, that looks good, don't forget to look at the p-values and other fit stats across models constrained or not. It is very feasible for loadings to be over 1 - unless they are standardized. How did you make the model identifiable: constrain latent variable variance to be 1 or one of the loadings to be 1?

Comment: Another test you should consider is to see if loadings are statistically different, constrain them all to be equal, and see if that fits equally good or worse. That will be a simpler model and easier to understand, and allow you to use Cronbach's alpha - otherwise you need another reliability coefficient.

Comment: Yes, I have a 1 on one measured variable for every latent variable. I apologize for my confusion, because I am really new at amos, never made a CFA before. No the measured variables are not standardized. :) As for the p-values, where do I look? Am I looking for the regression weights? because there everything except for one variable has a *** :-)

Comment: Looking at my model fit values, they dont look so good. chi²/df is >2, RMSEA is >.05 and CFI, GFI, AGFI, NFI are all <.90

Comment: I'm not familiar with AMOS, so I can't help you dig in the output to figure out what is where. Typically the asterisks mean statistically significant - I've never done a CFA where the coefficients are not statistically significant, so that they are highly significant doesn't tell you much. The model fit stats are not that great, as you suggest. This means you need to consider alternative forms of your measurement model.

Comment: See if you can figure out how to get AMOS to calculate modification indices. I can't really walk you through the entire process - there may be good online tutorials for how to do this in AMOS. But a modification index is calculated for each possible path in your diagram - between every observed variable, and between each observed variable and the latent variables. Take a look at the paths with the highest modification index, and choose the ones with the strongest theoretical relationship. Enter them into the model and compare fit.